# Flexicious - Close itemEditor

Tags: apache-flex, itemeditor, flexicious, flex-datagrid

I got a very stupid problem which I just can't resolve : I want to close an item Editor in my FlexDataGrid from **Flexicious**.

Indeed, when I hit the `Enter` key, I enter my `itemEditEndHandler` function, but then the itemEditor don't close (however it close correctly when hitting `Escape` or `Tab` key). I was first thinking to use a method like `datagrid.destroyItemEditor()` (like with the  common datagrid...) but there isn't any obvious methods or way to close it !!!

sadly, there isn't a lot of doc for the FlexDataGrid from Flexicious :'(

Did anybody already have meet this problem ? Do you know some good way to force the closing of the itemEditor ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try grid.bodyContainer.endEdit(grid.bodyContainer.getCurrentEditor()). 
We will add destroyItemEditor to the next release.

Comment: it doesn't work T_T, but if I double hit the 'Enter' key, my editor close ! :)

Comment: Create a small test case and send it to support so they can look at your issue.

Comment: OK, I send it as soon as I have time :) Thanks a lot